# Show data from multiple list into a single list

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have a sharepoint FBA application, where I have multiple list for multiple forms.

Now each form will have a status like approved, rejected, draft which will be based on a drop-down column in each list.

Now I want to show the forms

**i.e** items from each list into a single list on the basis of their status which is submitted, draft and rejected.

How should I approach to this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Would two web parts on one page work? Then you can see each list all on one page depending on what columns you display etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your not opting for a out of the box approach, then you can create a `SPGridView` programmatically and assign your custom data source to your `SPGridView`.

The `SPGridView` is the same control which SharePoint uses in its list view. 
Help : [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35536/Creation-of-a-SPGridview-Webpart-having-Pagination)

Comment: How to place a edit column in the grid, when we click on edit button in the grid it should automatically redirect us to the sharepoint edit form of that item. 
Note: I'm displaying data from multiple grid using SpQuery . So the item can be of any list in the grid